# Generalized Function as the Boundary of a Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory

I have been reading [this text](http://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/viewer.html?pdfurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.polytechnique.fr%2Fcmat%2Fvergne%2Fpublications2%2FRemplacer%2FEquivariantCohomology.pdf&clen=390280&chunk=true) from Michelle Verne on Equivariant Cohomology and stumbled upon this specific paragraph which I can't seem to make sense of:

> Let us point out some examples of non-compact manifolds $N$ where the equivariant symplectic volume exists in the sense of generalized functions. We will use the following generalized functions: $$Y^+ (\phi) := \int_0^\infty e^{i\phi t} dt, \qquad Y^- (\phi) := \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{i\phi t} dt, \qquad \delta_0(\phi) := \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\phi t} dt,$$ **Note that the generalized function $Y^+$ is the boundary value of the holomorphic function $\frac{1}{-i\phi}$ defined on the upper-half plane, so that it satisfies the relation $(-i\phi)Y^+(\phi) = 1$.**

I couldn't understand this last statement for the first generalized function since is not defined. She uses a definition of tempered distribution to make sense of it, though I didn't catch it either.

Has anyone seen this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what your concrete question is, so I'll just provide some general commentary. One way to think about $Y^+$ to is to consider an $\epsilon$ deformation of it into the complex plane (I am assuming $\phi$ is real-valued here). Consider $Y^+(\phi+i\epsilon)$. The $i\epsilon$ term makes the integral convergent, and in fact we have $Y^+(\phi+i\epsilon) = -\frac{1}{i(\phi+i\epsilon)}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. The latter is of course just $\frac{1}{-i\phi}$ in the upper-half plane, so $Y^+$ can be thought of as a boundary value.

Comment: More specifically, we have $Y^+(\phi) =\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{-1}{i(\phi+i\epsilon)}$, where the limit is taken in the distributional sense. To give slightly more context, there's a general theory of representing distributions as boundary values of holomorphic functions, and in that context they are called [hyperfunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction).

Comment: @EuYu thanks for the comment. In this case, we are taking $epsilon \to 0$, right? Further, how does one understand better this "distributional sense"?

Comment: @EuYu my issue really is to see this function as a jump or step function since it doesn't have a decreasing aspect ot it.